# Passing structure address from C to Lua and accessing its contents in Lua without copy of data

Tags: c, lua, stack, luabind

Consider I have a packet (network packet) and it is stored in an array in C. I have a module in Lua which can process this packet. Now I need to pass this packet to Lua for processing. I want to avoid copying of data. For this, I can use *userdata* or *lightuserdata*. But in this case, base address will be pushed to the top of stack and I need to write callbacks in Lua or write metatables for it in C.

I am facing difficulties for how to start writing a basic small callback in C. All I need is suppose I have a structure as below:

```
struct abc_{
    int a;
    int b;
    char* c;
} abc_t;

int arr1[] = {'100', '2', '4' , '5', '6'};
```

Now I have an array with some data in it. In C, I can typecast that array with this structure to get the particular values.

```
abc_t *test;
test = (abc_t *)arr1;
```

How can I do the same in Lua as well where I have passed the address of `arr1` on top of stack and the structure is defined in C? How can I get the values of variables `a`, `b` in Lua without copy?

**Question 2**

Suppose I am using C and using Lua stack for processing array.

If I want to access `a[2]`, where `a` is my table and 2 is the index, then `2` needs to be at top of the stack and I need to pass the location of `a` in stack as second argument to `lua_gettable()`. How can I do the same for a *structure*? I want to access the particular element of the structure. How to do that?

Comment: I don't thik you can get the values by this cast. Do you know the memory layout of `abc_t`? The pointer `c` will be invalid after the cast. And what value has the `int` `'100'`?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to copy the structure data from C into Lua, you need to box the pointer to the structure instance into a full *userdata* with a dedicated metatable. A light userdata is not flexible enough for this usage since you cannot assign a metatable to it.

The metatable should define `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods. If the index passed by Lua is `"a"`, `"b"` or `"c"`, the metamethods returns or assigns the corresponding structure field. The `__gc` metamethod could call `free` on the structure instance and a `__tostring` metamethod is always good for debugging.

If you use *luabind* as the question tag suggests, that library is able to generate the metatable for you. You can also write the binding by hand.

To answer your second question, if you define `__index` as suggested, you can access a field by first pushing the *userdata* on the stack, then pushing the field name as a string, then using `lua_gettable`. A shortcut for this is provided by the function `lua_getfield`.